# How to launch browser automatically after war deployment?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a war maven project and I want that when I deploy it on the server the default browser (Mozilla in my case) is launched automatically with the default url for access to the main page.
Of course with JBoss EAP6 I have just to run the Maven command `clean install jboss-as:deploy` to generate the war file and deploy it on the server.

Do I have to add something to the pom.xml or make any configurations in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it works good but juste for the maven phase : install but for the deploy no:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Run URL in system browser.</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <exec executable="start" vmlauncher="false">
                                <arg line="http://localhost:8080/mywarApp" />
                            </exec>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

I use eclipse and i made for goals "clean install jboss-as:deploy" into the run configurations. and when in click in , once the install phase is runing the browser is runing too but i want that it will happen when the deploy phase is end of runing  , have you any idea

Answer (score 1):

Use maven's exec plug-in.  More information [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin).

Comment: thx first , but it concerne java programme and not a war (web application ) ?